# Environment Variables in my own C Linux Shell?

Tags: c, linux, shell, environment-variables

I'm writing my own C Linux shell.

But I have to get and set environment variables.

I've had a little success using `getenv("HOME")` in my change directory part.

How do you get and set environment variables in my own shell though?

Comment: It's not really clear what's being asked here. Is the issue about how to "set" variables? As far as I know, the environment is determined at process start and stays unmodified there after. You can however keep track of newly set variables and pass them to the subprocesses.

Comment: I agree with Niklas. Please describe your problem in more detail.

Comment: Sorry, in the shell program I am writing, I need the user to be able to view, set and use the environment variables in this new shell. Such as show the $PATH and set $PATH etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

`int setenv(const char *name, const char *value, int overwrite);`

to change the environment belonging to Your current process. All child processes You create will inherit the changed environment.